# Getting the row and column of a string from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of unique strings and I want to find the row and column for a given string. I want these values because I'll be eventually exporting this dataframe to an excel spreadsheet. The easiest way I've found so far to get these values is the follwing:

```
jnames = list(df.iloc[0].to_frame().index)
for i in jnames:
    for k in df[i]:
        if 'searchstring' in str(k):
            print('Column: {}'.format( (jnames.index(i) + 1 ) ) )
            print('Row: {}'.format( list( df[i] ).index('searchstring') ) )
            break
```

Can anyone advise a solution that takes better advantage of the inherent capabilities of pandas?

Comment: Can you show us the dataframe?

Comment: Imported from a spreadsheet where row 0 is a header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reproducible code / data, I'm going to make up a dataframe and show one simple way:

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'b']])
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  b
```

**Solution**

```
result = list(zip(*np.where(df.values == 'b')))
```

**Result**

```
[(0, 1), (2, 2)]
```

**Explanation**

- `df.values` accesses the `numpy` array underlying the dataframe.
- `np.where` creates an array of coordinates satisfying the provided condition.
- `zip(*...)` transforms `[x-coords-array, y-coords-array]` into `(x, y)` coordinate pairs.

Comment: I prefer this route because it doesn't require that I know the header name, and it returns numerical coordinates instead of the column header. In my testing, `list(zip(*np.where(df.values == 'b')))` and `zip(*np.where(df.values == 'b'))` return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). This will return you a dataframe of rows that contain the slice you are looking for.

`df[df['<my_col>'].str.contains('<my_string_slice>')]`

Similarly, you can use [match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) for a direct match.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach not writing double for loops:

```
value_to_search = "c"
print(df[[x for x in df.columns if value_to_search in df[x].unique()]].index[0])
print(df[[x for x in df.columns if value_to_search in df[x].unique()]].columns[0])
```

The first will return the column name and the second will return the index. Combined together, you will get the index-column combination. Since you mentioned that all values in the df is unique, both lines will return exactly one value.

You might need a try-except if `value_to_search` might not in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

By using stack , data from jpp

```
df[df=='b'].stack()
Out[211]: 
0  1    b
2  2    b
dtype: object
```